# VB 2010 Radio Button Cost Calculation on a form

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I am running into an issue using VB 2010 - I am trying to calculate the cost of carpet based on the selection of 1 of 3 radio buttons.

I have this at the top of my form:

```
Private CarpetPrice, UnderlayPrice As Decimal
```

here is my code for the button click

```
Private Sub CostButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CostButton.Click
    ' Calculate button click
    ' Radio Button IF Statement for calculating cost
    If EconomyRadioButton.Checked Then
        UnderlayPrice = 3.95 And CarpetPrice = 12.95
    ElseIf DeluxeRadioButton.Checked Then
        UnderlayPrice = 4.95 And CarpetPrice = 15.49
    ElseIf PlushRadioButton.Checked Then
        UnderlayPrice = 5.95 And CarpetPrice = 19.95
    End If
    ' Start Calculations
    CarpetNumLabel.Text = (((Length1TextBox.Text * Width1TextBox.Text) / 1296) + ((Length2TextBox.Text * Width2TextBox.Text) / 1296) + _
        ((Length3TextBox.Text * Width3TextBox.Text) / 1296) + ((HallLengthTextBox.Text * HallWidthTextBox.Text) / 1296)) * 1.05
    UnderlayNumLabel.Text = CarpetNumLabel.Text
    TackNumLabel.Text = ((Length1TextBox.Text / 96) + (Width1TextBox.Text / 96) + (Length2TextBox.Text / 96) + (Width2TextBox.Text / 96) _
        + (Length3TextBox.Text / 96) + (Width3TextBox.Text / 96) + (HallLengthTextBox.Text / 96) + (HallWidthTextBox.Text / 96)) * 1.1
    ScrewNumLabel.Text = ((TackNumLabel.Text / 1.1) * 8) / 50
    CarpetCostLabel.Text = CarpetNumLabel.Text * CarpetPrice
    UnderlayCostLabel.Text = UnderlayNumLabel.Text * UnderlayPrice
    TackCostLabel.Text = TackNumLabel.Text
    ScrewCostLabel.Text = ScrewNumLabel.Text * 2.85

End Sub
```

Right now everything is running perfect except the carpet and underlay does not calculate the prices. Do I have to do something else to make the program recognize the status of the radio buttons when I click the button? -

I think my problem is at the :

```
CarpetCostLabel.Text = CarpetNumLabel.Text * CarpetPrice
UnderlayCostLabel.Text = UnderlayNumLabel.Text * UnderlayPrice
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't think you can use "AND" to do two assignments in one line like that in your IF block.

Comment: I think you are right. I just removed half of it and it worked for just the underlay. Guess I will have to add another IF block for the carpet side.

Comment: You don't need another if block, just take out the AND and put the second assignment on a new line.

Comment: Thanks! works perfect! I am taking my very first class and I have found this site extremely helpful. -thanks again. There a way I can flag your comment as a correct answer?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use AND to string together two different assignements.  Your IF block should be

```
If EconomyRadioButton.Checked Then
    UnderlayPrice = 3.95
    CarpetPrice = 12.95
ElseIf DeluxeRadioButton.Checked Then
    UnderlayPrice = 4.95
    CarpetPrice = 15.49
ElseIf PlushRadioButton.Checked Then
    UnderlayPrice = 5.95
    CarpetPrice = 19.95
End If
```

Comment: Great pick up! Glad you helped him out

Comment: Thanks @JeremyChild, sometimes it's the little things that trip us up, just need fresh eyes.

Answer (score -1):

use variables and do not use AND operator in if statement... ADN operator is use in IF condition like if a<20 and a>10 then  ..try try unt